# Jquery datepicker client options in yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, jquery-ui-datepicker, yii2-advanced-app

I am install Jquery date picker in Yii2 advanced template project using composer. Using below command

> php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui

I am confiugre date picker in form like below

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
   'options' => [
        'class'=>'cust-form',
        'aria-label'=>'Date of Birth',
        'placeholder'=>'Date of Birth'                                        
    ],
    'clientOptions'=>[                                       
        'showOn' => 'button',
        'buttonImage' => 'images/calendar.png',
        'buttonImageOnly' => true,                                        
        'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/yy',                                                                              
    ],
])->label('Date'); ?>
```

The showOn,buttonImage,buttonImageOnly options are working fine but the dateFormat option is not working and some css properties also not working properly like when i scroll the page, date picker will not scroll. I know this all are done with custom js and css, but why it is not working properly.

And last six months before i do same thing here all are working fine without write any custom css and js. Please help any one . Thanks in advance

Comment: In what way does the "dateFormat option" not work? What format does it output now?

Comment: Jun 5, 2017 this the output now, but i want this format 05/06/2017